# How to correctly display a saved HTML-file of a Facebook page in a browser?

Tags: python, html, selenium, browser, screen-scraping

I wrote the Python code using the Selenium library which opens Facebook, enters my account, finds the news page by its identifier (which starts with '@' symbol), and saves all the visible information to an HTML-file. I used this code to save the HTML-file:

```
with open(f'./post.html',"w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    source_data = browser.page_source
    bs_data = bs(source_data, 'html.parser')
    file.write(str(bs_data.prettify()))
    print(f'post.html')
```

Then I tried to open this post.html file to check the correctness of its saving. But all I see is at best a page with only the top menu displayed, at worst an empty page like this:

[Screenshot of the page displayed by the Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l2cp.png)

Sometimes the first post is displayed, but most of the time neither posts nor comments are displayed.
I tried 5 different browsers: Chrome, Firefox (also Firefox Developer Edition), Opera, Microsoft Edge, and Internet Explorer. To my surprise, the last one displayed the most data, however, poorly structured. The remaining 4 browsers displayed only some elements of the page or nothing at all.

I checked for these elements in the HTML code. And they are there, including posts with text and links, as well as all comments, the time of their adding, buttons etc.

Could you please advise, how to correctly display a saved HTML-file of a Facebook page in a browser?

Comment: In many cases there's a lot more to displaying a web page than just the HTML... there's JS, CSS, and so on. My guess is that you're missing some files. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I want to extract the text of the posts and the text of the comments. I think, the page markup is enough for me to get all the data I need. Moreover, I can successfully extract everything I need from the resulting html page. But I cannot display the saved html page in the browser. I need it to verify that my data collection program is working correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you are making this harder than it needs to be. Just scrape the data off the page while it's on the site. If you want to verify that your code is working correctly, take a screenshot of the page for comparison.

Comment: In fact, one post can have hundreds of comments. To collect them, you need to expand them. It would take tens and hundreds of screenshots to cover all the data, so it's not good for me. As for data collection, I started by collecting data directly from the site. After that, I faced a lot of problems that I didn't know before.

Comment: I borrowed the idea of saving an HTML-file and working with it here: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/collecting-public-data-from-facebook-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup-f0f918971000 . This code doesn't work as it should, so I rewrote it. The time to save the HTML-file is small, but it gives the opportunity to work with the content of the page on your local machine.